# A characterization of tangent space to level set of a smooth submersion

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is corollary 5.39 in John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

> **Corollary 5.39** Suppose $S \subseteq M$ is a level set of a smooth submersion
>   $\Phi=(\Phi^1,...\Phi^k): M \to \mathbb{R^k}$. A vector $v \in T_pM$
>   is tangent to $S$ if and only if $v\Phi^1=...=v\Phi^k=0$.

He said that the proof is immediate. But I can't figure it out.The author said it's a restatement of Proposition 5.38 in a special case in which the defining function takes its value in $\mathbb{R^k}$.

> **Proposition 5.38** Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $S \subseteq M$ s an embedded
>   submanifold. If $\Phi:U \to N$ is any local defining function map for
>   S, then $T_pS = \mathrm{Ker}d\Phi_p:T_pM \to T_{\Phi(p)}N$ for each $p
>  \in S\cap U$.

The step making me stuck is the sufficiency part. 
Suppose that $v\Phi^1=...=v\Phi^k=0$, in order to use Proposition 5.38, I want to show that $v \in \mathrm{Ker}d\Phi_p$, that is, $\forall f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^k)$, $v(f\circ \Phi)=0$. But I don't know how to reach this...The author said this proof is immediate, so may I miss something? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Corollary 5.39, Lee - Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770568/corollary-5-39-lee-introduction-to-smooth-manifolds)

Comment: @PaulFrost I do not think it is a good idea to close this question as a duplicate of the one you suggest. In particular, the question you suggest makes a clear reference to this question; marking this as a duplicate would mean that lower rep. users would not be able to follow this link, so wouldn't necessarily understand the question.

Comment: @user1729 The questions are identical, and if the present one is closed, it does not vanish so that users will still be able to follow the link. The reason for my vote is that I believe the answer to the other question is better then the one below.

Comment: My point is that they are *not* identical. The new question is asking about this one. Also, this question *does* vanish to lower rep. users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have that ${\rm d}\Phi_p(v) = ({\rm d}\Phi^1_p(v),\ldots, {\rm d}\Phi^k_p(v)) = (v\Phi^1,\ldots, v\Phi^k)$. So $v \in \ker {\rm d}\Phi_p$ if and only if $v\Phi^1 = \cdots = v\Phi^k = 0$.