# Corollary 5.39, Lee - Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am struggling with understanding how to prove Corollary 5.39 in Lee - *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

[image]

I found an answer on this post: [A characterization of tangent space to level set of a smooth submersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242264/a-characterization-of-tangent-space-to-level-set-of-a-smooth-submersion/3242266#3242266), but I do not understand the computation done there. Why do we have $d\Phi_p^i(v) = v\Phi^i$? By definition of the pushforward, for $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ we have $d\Phi_p^i(v)f = v(f\circ\Phi^i).$ But by the linked answer, it seems we would also have $d\Phi_p^i(v)f = (v\Phi^i)f$. But $(v\Phi^i)f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, not $\mathbb{R}$. What am I missing here?

Comment: We often identify $T_{t_0}\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ itself as $a\,  d/dt|_{t=t_0} \to a$, when we consider the derivative of any smooth real-valued function $df_p : T_pM \to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SiKucing is the idea to view $d\Phi_p^i(v)$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}$? If so, I do not see where to go from there. Do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that $d\Phi_p^i(v)$ is a vector in $T_{\Phi^i(p)}\mathbb{R} = \text{span }\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{\Phi^i(p)}\Big)$. So $d\Phi^i_p(v) = a \frac{d}{dt}\big|_{\Phi^i(p)}$ for some real number $a$. Since we often identify one dimensional vector $\lambda \, \frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t}$ with its component $\lambda$ itself, so (in our case) we write $d\Phi^i_p(v) = a$. But $a$ is exactly $v\Phi^i$ because
$$
a = \Big( a \, \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{\Phi^i(p)} \Big) \text{Id}_{\mathbb{R}} = d\Phi^i_p(v) \,\text{Id}_{\mathbb{R}} = v(\text{Id}_{\mathbb{R}} \circ \Phi^i ) = \color{blue}{v \Phi^i}.
$$
So we can write $d\Phi^i_p(v) = v \Phi^i$.

> The claim in the corollary still holds whether or not we apply this identification. Personally, i prefer to prove the corollary (without identification) as : $d\Phi_p(v) = 0 \in T_{\Phi(p)}\mathbb{R}^k$ if and only if
> $$
> 0=d\Phi_p(v)y^i =v (y^i \circ \Phi) = v\Phi^i,\quad i=1,\dots,k, 
> $$
> where $y^i : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ are standard coordinate functions of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: I think I understand it all, thank you very much!

Comment: @Victor You're welcome.

Comment: Very nice (+1). Actually you proved a sort of chain rule for derivations which I was not aware of before: If $\psi : M \to \mathbb R$ and $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are smooth, then for any $v \in T_pM$ one has $v(f \circ \psi) = f'(\psi(p))\cdot v(\psi)$. In fact, $d\psi_p(v) = a \frac{d}{dt} \mid_{\psi(p)}$, thus $d\psi_p(v)(f) = af'(\psi(p))$ and taking $f = id_{\mathbb R}$ gives $a = d\psi_p(v)(id_{\mathbb R})= v(id_{\mathbb R} \circ \psi) = v(\psi)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you. It's an honor to be upvoted by you Sir!

Comment: ... but it is unnecessary to use the formal "Sir" in this forum ;-)

Comment: @PaulFrost Sir yes Sir! :p